# Update one table data from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sql-update

I have source table and target table.
both source table and target table contains same columns `id,name,age,time`

i am updating source table by target table

so for this process i have tried this query.but it does't work.can you please tell me what is wrong in this query?

```
UPDATE source 
SET    source.name = target.name, 
       source.age = target.age, 
       source.time = target.time 
FROM   target 
       INNER JOIN source 
               ON source.id = target.id;
```

Comment: "what is wrong in this query?" Tell us what's wrong with it, do you get an exception or an incorrect result?

Comment: sir when i run that query i get this error >> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: You are getting an oracle error even if you use sql-server?

Comment: sir i use oracle 10g version for sql...and to be honest sir just now i started to learn sql few days before...so please help me out sir:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have heard is Oracle throws this error when updating a table by joining to another table. Try using an Subquery something like this

```
UPDATE source a
SET a.name = (
              select b.SURNAME
              from target b
              where a.id = b.id
              )
```

Comment: i tried this sir..and it only works for updating one column but how can update all the columns in one query

Comment: Have you tried adding multiple subqueries for each column im not sure but its worth trying.

Comment: i did try it sir but it says we cant use more than 3 subqueries like that